# Best key-value-store for my node.js service

Tags: node.js, solr, nosql, redis, key-value-store

I need to write a node.js service with an key-value-store as backend. My data looks like this:

```
Item
  Name: "Item 1"
  Attributes
    AttributeA: "ValueA"
    AttributeB: "ValueB"
    AttributeC: "ValueC"

Item
  Name: "Item 2"
  Attributes
    AttributeA: "ValueC"
    AttributeB: "ValueD"
```

I asked myself, which is the best backend for my requirements. I need a fast backend which is easy accessible from node.js and can handle big amounts of data (1-2 millionen items with 15-20 attributes). Important is, that the attributes can differ from item to item, so there are not 20 fix attributes. My later queries would look like this:

- Get all attributes for item 1
- Get all values for attributeA (from all items)
- Get all items which contain attributeB

Or maybe a noSQL DB like couchDB would be better? I would be appreciate for some hints. ;)

Thank you

Torben

Comment: Did you include Riak in your comparison?

Answer (score 3):

While it would probably depends on other parameters (like the size of the attributes, their type, the read/write ratio), I think a document database like MongoDb (ou couchDb, even though I haven't use it personnaly) would be a good fit. The reason being you want to query based on the 'value' of the attributes, which isn't possible in a database like Redis (without a change to the schema you proposed that is, and even though Redis is a remarkable fit for many usecases).

With documents like this: {name: "Item 1", AttributeA: "ValueA", AttributeB "ValueB"...}, you could implement the queries you mentionned with:

db.docs.find({name: "Item 2"}); (probably setting an index on name if you use this query often)
db.docs.distinct('attributeA');
db.docs.find({attributeB: {$exists: true}}});

and so on...

You can find a very good nodejs mongodb driver here : https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think mongoDB would be a good fit for you.  It's not exactly a key/value store though, it's a document store which is a bit different.

Here's what's good about mongo with nodejs:

- Index-able keys.
- Composite indexes allow for fast multi-attribute querying.
- Schema-less.  You can add/remove attributes however you see fit.  This would be good for you in cases that you don't have attributes for some items.
- Fast, everything I've ever done with it is amazingly quick.
- Made for tons of documents.  Your millions of items properly indexed will only make mongodb laugh at any doubts.
- Powerful.  Things like findAndModify and map/reduce give you amazing flexibility.  And most of the time you don't even need them.
- Familiar javascript syntax.  this.db.items.findOne({attrA : 'value'}) just feels right.

Here's some limitations:

- It seems like everyone's started a node-js/mongodb driver.  The most complete one, https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native, has some usability issues.  Your code ends up looking very callback driven.
- 16mb limit per document.  Not usually an issue, but something to be careful about.
- Sharding is an exercise in engineering/design.  It's not too complicated, but it does take a little forethought.  I would start with a single server and expand as necessary.
- You need a 64 bit server.  Not usually a problem in this day, but something to be aware of.

As always, know your tools.  I'd recommend reading this book: http://manning.com/banker/.   It's very well written.

Comment: +1 on the book recommendation, I highly recommend it for anyone with SQL experience (or not, it's friendly either way) that wants to understand MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using Redis it is a bit tricky.

To handle retrieval of all items that have a specific attribute. Have a set for each of the attributes. Every time you add an item, if it has the attribute add it to the set. When you want to retrieve all items with the attribute just request the whole set and then retrieve all items based on that.

Adding something

```
HMSET item1 attributeA value attributeB value
SADD set_attributeA item1
SADD set_attributeB item1
```

For your cases

1.

```
HGETALL item1
```

2.

```
SMEMBERS set_attributeA
```

then just iterate and get all values

```
HGET item1 attributeA
```

3.

```
use HGETALL instead of HGET
```

For node library use https://github.com/mranney/node_redis it has some nice additional things like making objects out of results of HGETALL and also storing objects in hashes with hmset